# odd coefficients of $(x+1)^{1000}$

Tags: combinatorics

If we expand $(x+1)^{1000}$ how many of the coefficients are even and how many odd?
I have found that each coefficient is ${1000 \choose k}$ where $0 \le K \le 1000$ but i don't know how to see if this is odd or even. Furthermore I don't know if there is a way to count all of the odd terms rather than going one by one

Answer (score 1):

A consequence of [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) is that

> $\binom{m}{n}$ is divisible by a prime $p$ if and only if at least one of the base-$p$ digits of $n$ is greater than the corresponding digit of $m$.

So, you start by expressing $1000$ in base $2$: ${1000}_{10} = {1111101000}_2$.

To apply the fact above, look at the places where there is a digit $0$ in $1111101000$. You need to make at least one of those $0$ a $1$. Now count in how many ways you can do that.

Comment: if found this on Wikipedia: A binomial coefficient {m \choose n}  is divisible by a prime p if and only if at least one of the base p digits of n is greater than the corresponding digit of m. \\ Do i need to also express all k's in base two and compare them?